# Supplying NSMutableArray type to Objective C function in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a library function written in Objective C that has takes a pointer to a NSMutableArray. However, when I try to call it with a Swift array I get this error:

```
DiscoverViewController.swift:34:20: Could not find an overload for 'init' that
accepts the supplied arguments
```

However, if I pass `nil`, it works. That makes sense.

Here is an example of the Objective-C:

```
int ex:(NSMutableArray *)in { return in.count; }
```

And an example of the Swift:

```
ex([1,2,3,4]) // doesn't compile

ex(nil) // does compile
```

What do I have to do to convert/cast the Swift array to the NSMutableArray type that my library function is looking for?

Here is the full method signature in case my example is too simplified:

```
- (id) initWithTitle: (NSString *) title place: (PublicPlaceInfo *) place
datetimeInterval: (DateTimeInterval *) datetimeInterval costBracket: (int)
costBracket creatorId: (PersonID) creatorId cover: (Url) cover experienceId: 
(ExperienceID) experienceId numJoined: (int32_t) numJoined relatedJoined: 
(NSMutableArray *) relatedJoined;
```

And then I know it is failing at the relatedJoined section because I converted all other potentially anonymous instantiations to variables. I have to say, this is certainly not the most helpful compile error..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ex([1,2,3,4]) // doesn't compile
```

This is because you're passing it a normal array, not a mutable array. Try converting it to a mutable array first: `ex(NSMutableArray([1,2,3,4]))`

```
ex(nil) // does compile
```

`nil` is a valid argument to `NSMutableArray?` which is why it works.

Comment: Ok so then I let the relatedJoined parameter equal to a `var mutArr = [1,2,3,4]` and it still does not compile. But according to the documentation, an array that is declared as "var" (not "let") is a mutable array.

Comment: @phileaton: Swift's `Array` is not the same as `NSArray`. [Docs reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) Think of an Array in Swift to be a SWArray :-)

Comment: Haha alright, I guess I'm just disappointed there isn't native support since for conversion since NSArray and NSMutableArray are so fundamental in Objective-C.